# 301 redirect Apache - source url with #

Tags: apache

Want to redirect the below source url with '#' in it

http://www.example.com/exite#gentle-clean to http://www.example.com/clear-gentle-200m

Below is the rewrite rule

**RewriteRule ^/exite#gentle-clean$ /clear-gentle-200m? [L,R=301]**

Need help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is any way you can do that, anything following a `#` character in a hypertext address is just a directive for user agent, which should indicate the anchor element, for example by scrolling to and/or highlighting the phrase.

If you run tcpdump on Apache server while requesting `http://www.example.com/exite#gentle-clean` and `http://www.example.com/exite`, you will see that there is no difference at all, all that server gets is `GET /exite HTTP/1.1` so there is no way #phrase can be used in server side RewriteRule *Pattern*.